# codeigniter active record delete function not working

Tags: codeigniter

I have a function written to delete entries from a table called stack. I have written similar function for other tables and it works. For this its not working, but no errors too. How can I find out whats wrong?

Controller entry:

```
function delete_tag($id)
        {

        $this->Mrestaurant->delete_tag($id);
        echo 'deleted!';    

        }
```

Model Entry:

```
function delete_tag($id)
    {
    $this->db->where('id', '$id'); 
    $this->db->delete('stack'); 
    }
```

Database and all i have preloaded:

```
$this->load->database();
$this->load->model('Mdb','',TRUE);
```

Every other db functions are working like adding, updating, deleting other datas etc... I'm confused because there is no error. And I don't know how to find out whats wrong.

**Update**
This worked in model

```
$this->db->delete('stack', array('id' => $id));
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at your code, I expect this line needs to be corrected:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

Notice that there are no single quotes (or any quotes) around `$id`. Your second example worked, because it is an alternative to your first, except this time you didn't use single quotes by accident.